# Why is mypy treating third party attribute as None type?

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to check type annotations in a python module with mypy. But as I'm importing ruamel.yaml and try to set the width with an int value.

```py
    yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
    yaml.width = 200
```

mypy keeps complaining about it, because ruamel.yaml sets width in the constructor to None, and for some reason mypy thinks it's a None type now.

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "None")
```

I tried to set `no_strict_optional = True` still no change. So now I ignored it, but I wish to understand why it's not defaulting to an optional value or gives me the opportunity to assign a correct type without touching ruamel.yaml's code.

Comment: I would suggest you write a .pyi file with type annotations for this library (or at least enough of them to silence the error) or contribute type annotations to the library itself. You can see how pyi files are done for the stdlib https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/stdlib/3

Comment: This is a bug in ruamel -- it's set up to tell mypy to use the type hints directly within its own source code, and `YAML.width` is set by doing `self.width = None` in [main.py](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/src/bace8dc0e8f5d950b4e9a62457a7d892626f8e81/main.py#lines-142) instead of `self.width = None  # type: Optional[int]`. There was an issue opened about this [around when your question was posted](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml/issues/322/missing-mypy-type-definitions-for-some). Not sure if that was you or not, but I figured it'd be worth mentioning here either way.

Comment: No I didn't open it, I just upvoted/attached myself to it. But if a type is set to "None", shouldn't it be `Optional[Any]` by default?

Comment: actually I did open it :D

Comment: @Boris is it possible to write only partial stubs? Do you know of a good tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: @tuexss yes. [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) says: Stub files may be incomplete. To make type checkers aware of this, the file can contain the following code:

`def __getattr__(name) -> Any: ...` Any identifier not defined in the stub is therefore assumed to be of type `Any`

Comment: @Boris cool, thanks for that hint.

Comment: @tuexss you're welcome. Sorry for not being more helpful, I haven't really used Python's type annotations. I still encourage you to open source your annotations for this library, if you end up writing them.

Comment: @tuexss you might want to use `stubgen` to generate stubs for the library instead of writing partial stubs. You can leave the variables you don't care about as `Any`. https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stubgen.html